# Guidance to implement war card game (Elixir)

Tags: algorithm, elixir

I'm trying to implement the [war game](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/war) in Elixir

This is the brief game description:

> The game starts with a shuffled deck of cards. The deck will be passed into your program already shuffled (details below). The cards are dealt in an alternating fashion to each player, so that each player has 26 cards.
> In each round, both players reveal the top card of their pile. The player with the higher card (by rank) wins both cards, placing them at the bottom of their pile. Aces are considered high, meaning the card ranks in ascending order are 2-10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace.
> If the revealed cards are tied, there is war! Each player turns up one card face down followed by one card face up. The player with the higher face-up card takes both piles (six cards – the two original cards that were tied, plus the four cards from the war). If the turned-up cards are again the same rank, each player places another card face down and turns another card face up. The player with the higher card takes all 10 cards, and so on.
> When one player runs out of cards, they are the loser, and the other the winner. If, during a war, a player runs out of cards, this counts as a loss as well.

And this is technical details:

> Input: The input to your program, representing a shuffled deck of cards, will be a permutation of 52 integers, where each integer between 1-13 occurs four times. The integers in this permutation correspond to cards according to the following table (four kings, four tens, four threes, and so on). Notice that we don’t bother representing the suit because the game of War doesn’t require it.
> The game: Your program will deal two piles from the input permutation. How you represent your piles is completely up to you. Once the piles are dealt, “play” the game in your program until one player runs out of cards. Once again, how you manage your piles during the game is completely up to you. Keep going until one player runs out of cards.
> When cards are added to the bottom of a player’s pile, they should be added in decreasing order by rank. That is, first place the highest ranked card on the bottom, then place the next highest ranked card beneath that. This is true of wars as well. If a player wins six cards as a result of a war, those cards should be added to the bottom starting with the highest rank and ending with the smallest. Ace has the highest rank, Two has the lowest.
> Output: Your program will return the pile of the winning player. This pile should contain all 52 integers from the original input permutation and be in the correct order according to how the game played out.

There are some test cases (this is not homework):

```
defmodule WarTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  describe "War" do
    test "deal_1" do
      t1 = [1,1,1,1,13,13,13,13,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,10,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2]
      r1 = [1,1,1,1,13,13,13,13,12,12,12,12,11,11,11,11,10,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2]
      assert War.deal(t1) == r1
    end

    test "deal_2" do
      t2 = [1,13,1,13,1,13,1,13,12,11,12,11,12,11,12,11,10,9,10,9,10,9,10,9,8,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,2,2,2,2]
      r2 = [4,3,2,2,2,2,4,3,4,3,4,3,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,8,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,10,9,10,9,10,9,10,9,12,11,12,11,12,11,12,11,1,13,1,13,1,13,1,13]
      assert War.deal(t2) == r2
    end

    test "deal_3" do
      t3 = [13,1,13,1,13,1,13,1,11,12,11,12,11,12,11,12,9,10,9,10,9,10,9,10,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,8,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,2,2,2,2]
      r3 = [4,3,2,2,2,2,4,3,4,3,4,3,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,8,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,10,9,10,9,10,9,10,9,12,11,12,11,12,11,12,11,1,13,1,13,1,13,1,13]
      assert War.deal(t3) == r3
    end

    test "deal_4" do
      t4 = [10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
      r4 = [1,1,13,12,9,5,11,4,9,3,8,7,7,2,13,10,12,5,10,4,9,6,8,3,1,1,13,12,7,5,11,4,9,3,8,6,7,2,13,10,12,5,11,11,10,8,6,4,6,3,2,2]
      assert War.deal(t4) == r4
    end

    test "deal_5" do
      t5 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
      r5 = [1,10,13,8,11,9,8,7,11,8,13,7,13,6,12,6,9,5,8,5,7,4,7,4,11,6,12,10,6,3,2,2,12,5,9,3,10,4,9,2,10,3,5,2,1,1,1,13,12,11,4,3]
      assert War.deal(t5) == r5
    end
  end
end
```

I also made a public repo of this challenge: https://github.com/zoedsoupe/war.ex

### Minimal Example

Assuming those test cases cited above and that thee deck is already shuffled, this is the main part of my implementation:

```
defmodule War do
  defp play_game(p1, p2, tied \\ [])

  defp play_game([], p2, tied), do: p2 ++ tied
  defp play_game(p1, [], tied), do: p1 ++ tied

  # War, cards tied
  defp play_game([c | xs], [c | ys], tied) do
    cards = Enum.sort([c, c] ++ tied, :desc)
    play_game(xs, ys, cards)
  end

  # Normal game turn
  defp play_game([x | xs], [y | ys], tied) do
    cards = Enum.sort([x, y] ++ tied, :desc)

    if x > y do
      play_game(xs ++ cards, ys)
    else
      play_game(xs, ys ++ cards)
    end
  end
end
```

With this implementation, only the first test case succeeds and I'm not understand why it's failing into another test cases and also how can I achieve this

Comment: After I pass all test cases I'll improve the Queue implementation, using two lists: one for enqueue and another to dequeue, so it gets more performatic

Comment: I'm sorry--it's not clear to me; what is the question here?  Are you asking for guidance in coding this with a queue?  Also it might benefit you to examine this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Yeah, i need guidance to be able to pass these test cases (it's not homework, it's a challenge for myself).  How could I provide a minimal example? I already shared all the code,  test cases and the complete project on the repository link

Comment: 1.) Honestly, when I first saw your question I thought to myself "They're working on homework" but I don't mind someone asking for help on homework if they've done some work themselves.   2.)Minimal example: Try thinking of the smaller issue you're trying to solve.  Maybe in this case post one failing test and as much code as you need to demonstrate it.  Posting _all_ the code and is the opposite of minimal example. Surely some of your code is working?  We don't necessarily need to see that part.

Comment: done! I simplified the game implementation because I wanted to understand why those test cases failed! So I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

Not all the shuffled decks have a winner, in the first place. Consider a deck of 2 suits each having 2 ranks (1♠️, 2♠️, 1♥️, 2♥️.) Shuffle it as `{[1♠️, 2♠️], [2♥️, 1♥️]}` and see how the loop becomes infinite. The same might be without loss of generality applied to any deck with even number of cards.

Also, there might be draw during war, when both players run out of cards simultaneously.

The last, but not the least, there must be a rule of what order the pile won is stacked under the winner’s half-deck in.

---

That said, I’d start with detecting loops within the `Queue` implementation to declare draw if that particular combination has been already seen.

Also, I’d avoid at attempt to *use two lists*, it’s surely a sign of premature optimization and I doubt it makes any sense.

Comment: So i preferred to use the `Queue` data structure as a simple module and indeed using two lists is a premature optimization

Comment: So, in this assignment, there is no drawing... the first player to run out of cards will always be the loser, even the second one has no cards too. My Queue implementation had some minor errors that I fixed but I really can't understand  those test cases failures

Comment: I'm searching for some other implementations and they seems to to almost the same I do

Comment: Like, take a look at https://github.com/bstakes/war-cardgame or https://github.com/Bovojon/BlackJack-War-Games/blob/master/aabdul15_mashres15_war.hs. both fails for tests cases so I imagine these test cases are wrong or some rule is missing

Comment: What would be wrong with implementing a check for loops and exit with `:draw` reason?

Comment: it would not met the assignment rules :/ it expects always to have a winner, even though it is a drawing. all tests cases expect a final "winner" deck